# Slow Down SWTBot execution

Tags: eclipse, wiki, slowdown, swtbot

I would like to slow down SWTBot Execution.

I have already found this wiki:
https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWTBot/FAQ#Can_I_slow_down_the_execution_speed_of_SWTBot_tests.3F

But for me it doesn't work.

My DEFAULT_POLL_DELAY in SWTBotPreferences look like that:

`public static final long DEFAULT_POLL_DELAY = toLong(System.getProperty(KEY_DEFAULT_POLL_DELAY, "500"), 500);`

So, `SWTBotPreferences.DEFAULT_POLL_DELAY = 1000;` can't work...

With `System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swtbot.playback.poll.delay", "1200");` it doesn't work for me.

Thank you,

Antoine

Comment: To slow down execution you should use `System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swtbot.playback.delay", "1200");`, not ...`.poll.`...

Comment: Yes, thank you. It is possible as well to use `SWTBotPreferences.PLAYBACK_DELAY = 1200;` instead of `System.setProperty`

Comment: Yes, I haven't tried it yet, but I think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To slow down execution use

- `System.setProperty("org.eclipse.swtbot.playback.delay", "1200");`, without ...`.poll.`... or
- `SWTBotPreferences.PLAYBACK_DELAY = 1000;` instead of `SWTBotPreferences.DEFAULT_POLL_DELAY = 1000;`